# Parse javascript count method on queries

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, pfquery

In Parse's javascript API, does the count method not do anything if no objects are returned? I'm trying to query for a new table I just added, and I can't seem to get a query to return results.

```
var contactObj = Parse.Object.extend("Contact");
var contactQuery = new Parse.Query(contactObj);
contactQuery.equalTo("phone", req.body.From);

    contactQuery.count({
      success: function(number) {
        // There are number instances of MyClass.
        console.log("something");
      },
      error: function(error) {
    // error is an instance of Parse.Error.
            console.log("error");
    }
});
```

In this code, when run, no console.logs are received, but the enclosing method that I call does print that it has been run. Does count not get to success OR failure if the count is 0?

Answer (score 1):

Your are missing the response.success and response.error calls, but console logs are still writing.
See below

Your exact piece of code is returning in your workstation console "success/error was not called" when running.
But still in parse portal console you see "something" output...

Output parse console in your local machine:

```
{"code":141,"error":"success/error was not called"}
```

Output parse portal in Logs

```
Failed with: success/error was not called
I2015-01-14T09:28:26.174Z] something
```

I'd added below two lines:

```
response.success("something success");
response.error("something error");
```

so actual code will be like the one below:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("StackOverflowTesting", function(request, response) {
   var contactObj = Parse.Object.extend("Contact");
   var contactQuery = new Parse.Query(contactObj);
   contactQuery.equalTo("phone", req.body.From);
   contactQuery.count({
         success: function(number) {
           // There are number instances of MyClass.
           console.log("something success console");
           response.success("something success");
         },
         error: function(error) {
         // error is an instance of Parse.Error.
             console.log("something error console");
             response.error("something error");
     }
   });
```

});

outputs
workstation console:

```
{"result":"something success"}
```

Parse portal Log:

```
Result: something success 
I2015-01-14T09:29:54.355Z] something success console
```

Comment: Sorry this wasn't clear, but there are below this query more queries and a push, which at the lowest level will call response.success/response.error. I thought that if I did those too early then the execution would terminate before reaching my further code.

Comment: Nothing in the OP suggests this code was running in the cloud, sounds more like it was being run client-side and having issues when the table is empty.

Comment: @BHendricks you can pass your `callback` (or `response`) function(s) down the chain, e.g. `function (req, callbacks) {
                    var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
                    query.containedIn('phoneNumber', request.body.phoneNumbers);
                    query.find(callbacks);
                };
`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where console.logs were not called from success and error blocks. This was caused due to an infinite while loop after the query. Something of this kind -

```
    var c = 0;
    var query = new Parse.Query("XXXXX");
    query.equalTo("YYYY","abc");
    query.count({
                success: function(count) {
                         c += 1;
                         console.log("success");
                },
                error: function(error) {
                       c += 1;
                       console.log("failure");
                }
                });
   while (c < 1){
   }
   ..........
```

Node.js is asynchronous but it's also single-threaded. Make sure you do not have any such code blocks which are holding up the execution.

Also, query.count gets to success even if the no. of results is 0.